# How to plot a Seaborn FacetGrid with different variables per row?

Tags: pandas, plot, statistics, seaborn

I have a Pandas data frame with one column of categorical variables `C={A,B,C,..}` and a number of numerical columns `var1`,`var2`,...,`var_n`. I would like to plot a grid where each row contains a histogram on of the numerical columns conditioned on all different categorical variables(one per column). It is pretty straightforward for only one numerical variable, however, I am having trouble extending it to the multiple variables. I could probably do this via subplot but I am wondering if it exists directly in Seaborn

This is what I want,

```
A-list(var1) | B-hist(var1) | C-hist(var1)...
A-hist(var2) | B-hist(var2) | C-hist(var2)...
A-hist(var3) | B-hist(var3) | C-hist(var3)...
....
```

Comment: That should be straight forward once you have your dataframe in a stacked fashion with 3 columns (categories, variables, data). Then you can call `FacetGrid(df, col="categories", row="variables")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as @ImportanceOfBeingErnest noted in a comment, there is no need for fancy plotting wizardry if you set up the Pandas data frame correctly in a *tidy way*. That is, as rows with `(categories, variables, data)` where the variables are now a column of labels indicating the previous column names the data belong to. Usually, this structure happens automatically when your data for the given variables have different lengths.

After putting your data frame in this format, `(Categories, Variables, Data)`, you can just plot them as usual with matplotblib and seaborn,

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col='Categories', row='Variables')
g = g.map(plt.hist, "Data")
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9)
g.fig.suptitle('Histogram of variables conditioned on categories')
plt.show()
```